# How to implement a Navigation Drawer layout?

Tags: navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I want to implement a navigation drawer layout where I want to use a toggle bar that opens or closes the navigation drawer.

Can you send me the code both Main activity java and xml file?

Answer (score 1):

I did a new code that works fine:

**Navigation_Header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="#72B569"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Nazmul Islam"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nazmul@voltagelab.com"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showInd="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/homes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/work"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_work_black_24dp"
            android:title="Work" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communication">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/contact"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_phone_black_24dp"
                android:title="Contact" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                android:title="Share" />

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**Values styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Manifext.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

**Activitymain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.navigationscroll;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    NavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

//------- Rotate not refresh new state --------------------

        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame,
                    new first()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.homes:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame,
                        new first()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.work:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame,
                        new second()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Share Press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```